# Infinity scroll with angularjs spring mvc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

This controller return list of invoices(model.addAttribute("invoices", invoiceService.getAllInvoices(user.getId()))) then redirect to invoices jsp page (Method invoiceService.getAllInvoices(user.getId()) is success).

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/get-all-invoices" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllInvoices(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    model.addAttribute("invoices", invoiceService.getAllInvoices(user.getId()));
    model.addAttribute("title", "Invoices");
    return "invoices";
}
```

Then, in invoices jsp page will get list of invoices. However, The page isn't load the first 20 invoices, and loadmore function isn't working. Thanks for help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" />"        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />"        type="text/css"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />"        type="text/css"></script>

<script src="<c:url value="/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js" />"        type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app.js" />"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="InvoiceController"ng-app="app">
  <table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="invoice in invoices | limitTo:totalDisplayed"><td>{{invoice.name}}</td>
    
    </tr>
  </table>
  <btn class="btn" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</btn>
  <script>

var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('InvoiceController', function ($scope) {
 
  
   
    $scope.invoices = invoices;
  
    $scope.totalDisplayed = 20;
    
    $scope.loadMore = function () {
     
      $scope.totalDisplayed += 20;  
    };
     
  
});


</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I can't see $http call to get data from server in your angular code.

Comment: Since  you're returning a complete view and all the content (including javascript code) inside it, I think you should asign the object of invoices as a jsp var. Something like this: $scope.invoices = ${invoices}

Comment: Thanks Diego. When I use $scope.invoices = ${invoices}. The invoces jsp page show all invoice.name, not limit to 20 invoices. And I add alert(sth) in this script to make sure it run, alert is not called, when  I delete $scope.invoices = ${invoices}, alert(sth) is called. Sth wrong ?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular side its correct, wrong in spring response type.

You are returning String, AngularJS ng-repeat will iterate list of objects only but You iterating String value.

This is wrong:

public String getAllInvoices(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
model.addAttribute("invoices", invoiceService.getAllInvoices(user.getId()));
model.addAttribute("title", "Invoices");
return "invoices";
```

}

This should be:

public **List** getAllInvoices(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
return invoiceService.getAllInvoices(user.getId());
```

}

invoiceService.getAllInvoices(user.getId()) service should return list of invoices objects.

Comment: Thanks for your option, but this method not return string, it assign invoiceService.getAllInvoices(user.getId()) -> invoices, so invoices will be a list, then in jsp I call this list sth like ${invoices}. When I use $scope.invoices = ${invoices}. The invoces jsp page show all invoice.name, not limit to 20 invoices, sth wrong, thanks